# Random number generator without repetition Class in Java

Tags: java, android, random

First of all, I'm a newbie Android App developer. In my App I need a class which generates random numbers in a given range avoiding repetition. I've searched much for this issue, but I haven't found any concrete solution for my case. Well, thought I found one which I slightly readapt, but it's not working fine. The code is the following one:

```
public class NoRepeatRandom {

  private int[] number = null;
  private int N = -1;
  private int size = 0;
  public NoRepeatRandom(int minVal, int maxVal)
  {
    N = (maxVal - minVal) + 1;
    number = new int[N];
    int n = minVal;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      number[i] = n++;
    size = N;
  }

  public void Reset() { size = N; }

   // Returns -1 if none left
  public int GetRandom()
  {
    if(size <= 0) return -1;
    int index = size * (int)Math.random();
    int randNum = number[index];

    // Swap current value with current last, so we don't actually
    // have to remove anything, and our list still contains everything
    // if we want to reset
    number[index] = number[size-1];
    number[--size] = randNum;

    return randNum;
  }
}
```

When I call GetRandom() I don't achieve the expected result, because it always returns the minimum number of the range given. For example:

```
NoRepeatRandom nrr = new NoRepeatRandom(0, 10);
int yes = nrr.GetRandom();
//Here I create a Toast just to see the numbers that the method is returning.    
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(yes), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

And the result is: 0,0,0,0,0,0....
For range (5,10) the result is 5,5,5,5....

Does anybody knows what is wrong with the code? I would really appreciate any help!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this line is issue.

```
int index = size * (int) Math.random();
```

This evaluates to **Zero** always.

**Edit:**

Just consolidating comments from  Jeroen Vannevel and OP.

[Math.random()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) will return a value between 0.0 and 1.0, which when cast with `(int)` will always evaluates to ZERO. You ca use as below.

```
int index = (int) (size * Math.random());
```

Comment: Yup, that looks like the problem. To fix it: int index = (int)(size * Math.random());

Comment: To clarify: `Math.random()` returns a value between 0.0 and 1.0. By casting that to `int` first you disregard everything after the period and thus you end up with `0`. `0` times anything remains 0.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot, that was the problem. Now the toast is giving different numbers :) 
The problem now is that the numbers given are repeated TT I must recheck the code.
I got this sequence (for the same code written before, adding the change: int index = (int)(size * Math.random());) :
7,10,6,8,0,7,8,4,2,1,8,6,0,9     

(numbers shown via Toast when I click a button, which have a onclick where the NoRepeatRandom class is called).

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `Random` class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNo = random.nextInt(10);  // 0 to 9
```

Comment: I think this is it - Math.random() returns 0-1, so cast to an int it will pretty much always be 0

Comment: Yeah, that was it, Math.random() giving 0-1 numbers. Thank you both! :)